# How should Apache IoTDB query latest values when inserting multiple fields?

Tags: database, insert, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use Version 1.0 of Apache IoTDB. After inserting 40 fields in IoTDB, why can only 3 fields be queried each time? I want to check the latest value of these fields, but all fields can only be queried without adding "last". Should I use a different query statement to check all these fields, or how should I write my statement when using "last"?

Answer (score 0):

There is bug with using "last" to query in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0. You can try the latest Version 1.1 which fixed this problem.

```
select last <Path> [COMMA <Path>]* from < PrefixPath > [COMMA < PrefixPath >]* <whereClause> [ORDER BY TIMESERIES (DESC | ASC)?]
```